# VB.Net Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Tags: vb.net

Index was out of range. I was trying to put the selected rows in `frm_Guest` to `frm_Main`:

```
Private Sub dgview_GPIGuest_CellContentClick_1(sender As Object, e As 
    DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgview_GPIGuest.CellContentClick
  Dim ID As String = dgview_GPIGuest.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString()
  Dim FName As String = dgview_GPIGuest.SelectedRows(0).Cells(1).Value.ToString()
  Dim LName As String = dgview_GPIGuest.SelectedRows(0).Cells(2).Value.ToString()
  Dim Gender As String = dgview_GPIGuest.SelectedRows(0).Cells(3).Value.ToString()
  Dim Address As String = dgview_GPIGuest.SelectedRows(0).Cells(4).Value.ToString()
  Dim IDType As String = dgview_GPIGuest.SelectedRows(0).Cells(5).Value.ToString()
  Dim IDNumber As String = dgview_GPIGuest.SelectedRows(0).Cells(6).Value.ToString()

  frm_Main.txt_GPIId.Text = ID
  frm_Main.txt_GPIFirstName.Text = FName
  frm_Main.txt_GPILastName.Text = LName
  frm_Main.txt_GPIAddress.Text = Address
  frm_Main.txt_GPIIDNumber.Text = IDNumber
  frm_Main.txt_GPIIdType.Text = IDType
  If Gender = "Male" Then
    frm_Main.rb_GPIMale.Checked = True
  Else
    frm_Main.rb_GPIFemale.Checked = True
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please format your question

Comment: So what was the index at the time that the exception was thrown and what was the size of the collection? Most likely the issue is that you don't understand what a selected row is in a `DataGridView`. You should not be using `SelectedRows` in that context. The `e` parameter gives you the index of the column and row of the cell whose content was clicked. That's what you should be using.

Answer (score 0):

I think the confusion is between selected row and cell click. A row is selected by clicking in the far left column of the grid. The entire row will highlight. When a single cell is clicked there are no selected rows; therefore index 0 is out of range. If you want to use this event then use the `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` as @jmcilhinney suggested.

```
Debug.Print($"Row {e.RowIndex.ToString}, Column {e.ColumnIndex}")
```

Comment: `When a single cell is clicked there are no selected rows` - what if `SelectionMode` is set to `FullRowMode` or `FullRowSelect` is enabled ?

Comment: Well, I guess it isn't as the OP is getting index out of range.

Comment: could be .... Or couldn't be... the OP didn't even mention where he get's the error

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, not sure if you already did it but you must set the `SelectionMode` property to `FullRowSelect` either in design time or from code behind :

```
 Dgvw1.SelectionMode = DataGridviewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
```

The reason for this is to select the entire row when you click on a cell.

Moving on, the usage of `SelectedRows` is quite unnecessary here(assuming `MultiSelect` is not set). What i understand so far is that you want to get the column value of the selected row, right ? Here's a quick code :

```
Dim row = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex; ''This gets the row index(or count) of the selected row
Dim col = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex; ''This gets the column index(or count) of the selected row

Dim ID As String = dataGridView1.Rows(row).Cells(col).Value.ToString())  ''Now note that here i am getting the selected column/cell's value, you can change it with any required index :)
```

Hope this helps.

**The reason you received the error**

It's pretty simple to understand. It is somewhat like you are trying to subtract 1 from 0 which will result in -1 but in programming(in cases of collections) , it is an invalid value. I assume when you select a cell, your entire row isn't selected(default behavior)(read the beginning of the answer to fix). That's why `SelectedRows()`, which is supposed to return all selected rows, returns null. And finally you get the error